# ASP.NET 2.0 IIS Setup

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

Good afternoon,

This should be an easy one.  I've done the cookie-cutter default ASP.NET 2.0 installation, but I have a couple of programming errors in my application.

When I access the webpage on the server itself, I get a detailed ASP error message.  However, when i try to run the same thing from a client machine, I just get a no-descriptive 500 error without any exception details.

How do I make it so detailed exception messages are sent to remote clients?

Regards,
Alan.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the [CustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx) mode to Off. I hope this is not for public facing websites.

Off - Specifies that custom errors are disabled. The detailed ASP.NET errors are shown to the remote clients and to the local host.

Comment: Thank you very much for the really quick response -- 1 minute!

Answer (score 1):

You dont want to do that. Its a security practice violation.

Just think how much easier you make it for an attacker, when your source code and app version (among other things) are displayed on the screen.

Comment: This is a valid point, but this is not going to be called directly by users.  It is just a web service called by another program.

Comment: Just make sure you dont forget to turn it back off before its deployed. If its exposed to programs, then its exposed to users. Anyone with Fiddler or Firebug will be able to dig into it if you aren't careful.